# How to solve Failed to retrieve management_url from token issue in order to login to Openstack's Horizon?

Tags: authentication, openstack, openstack-horizon, openstack-keystone

**Attempt**

Reading [this Q&A](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/11395/failed-to-retrieve-management_url-from-token/) did not solve the issue.

*/etc/keystone/keystone.conf*

provided if requested

*/etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings*

provided if requested

*User*

A user has been created and it is possible to authenticate

```
keystone tenant-create --name demo --description "Demo Tenant" && \
keystone user-create --name demo --pass DEMO_PASS --email EMAIL_ADDRESS && \
keystone user-role-add --tenant demo --user demo --role _member_
```

**Result**

Once the user has been authenticated the UI indicates the following:

```
Something went wrong!

An unexpected error has occurred. Try refreshing the page. If that doesn't help, contact your local administrator.
```

*/var/log/httpd/error_log*

```
[Tue Dec 02 16:22:07.313065 2014] [:error] [pid 9684] Failed to retrieve manageme
nt_url from token
[Tue Dec 02 16:22:07.321801 2014] [:error] [pid 9684] Internal Server Error: /das
hboard/auth/login/
...
EmptyCatalog: The service catalog is empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [this documentation](http://fosshelp.blogspot.nl/2013/05/horizon-keystone-emptycatalog-service.html) and executing the following commands:

```
keystone service-create --name=keystone --type=identity --description="Identity Service" && \
keystone service-list

keystone endpoint-create \
 --region RegionOne \
 --service-id=<service-list-id> \
 --publicurl=http://<ip>:5000/v2.0 \
 --internalurl=http://<ip>:5000/v2.0 \
 --adminurl=http://<ip>:35357/v2.0 && \
keystone endpoint-list
```

solved the issue. It is possible to login to Horizon now.